# bash - source is not working

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a script which is sourcing the `bashrc` file and i'm also sourcing another file, the `bashrc` file is passing the source operation, but my second file doesn't passing it.
Here is my fundtions:

```
function setEnv () {
    envFile=/etc/profile.d/p4v.sh
    echo export p4bin=$p4Dir/bin > $envFile
    echo export P4USER='$USER' >> $envFile
    echo export P4CONFIG=.p4settings >> $envFile
    echo export PATH='$p4bin':'$PATH' >> $envFile
    sleep 5
    chmod a+x /etc/bashrc
    PS1='$ '
    source /etc/bashrc

}

function setAutoCompletion () {
    autoCompletionFile=$1/p4-completion.bash
    cp $autoCompletionFile /etc/bash_completion.d/p4-completion.bash
    chmod a+x /etc/bash_completion.d/p4-completion.bash
    PS1='$ '
    source /etc/bash_completion.d/p4-completion.bash
}
```

Another thing that i don't know how to solve is, once the script has finished, i need to open a new shell in order to see the sourced variables that were inside the `bashrc` file.
Any idea how to solve both issues?

Comment: how do you execute this script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the variables in the .bashrc file in your currently executing shell, you have to source your file containing the above code.

Like the previous responder said, how do you run your above script? Do you execute it or source it?

Comment: When you execute a script you launch a new /bin/sh process and any and all variables you set in that script dies with that process when it exits and you get your shell prompt back.

If you source a script, it executes as part of your already running /bin/sh, so variables set continue to llive on in the process of your shell.